# Time Complexity - T(n) =T(9n/10) + O(n)

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, quicksort

What will be the time complexity of this Equation ?
Using Master's Algorithm , I am getting answer as O(n) using a < b^k case .
 But the correct answer is O(nlogn) .
How ?

Comment: What have you tried?  Could you show your working?

Answer (score 1):

Using [**Master's Theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) for an equation like this:

[image: T]

you should first calculate this value:

[image: log_b a]

In this case we have:

- a=1
- [image: 10/9]

so the value of c will be something like:

[image: c]

which means:
[image: n^c]

Now it depends on f(n) to choose the right case of Master's method. It can be case 2 or 3 depending on f(n). If f(n) is a constant, then according to case 2, `T(n) = O(nlogn)` and if f(n) is a polynomial of n, according to case 3, `T(n) = O(n)`.

Using recursive method, I also got O(n). How do you know it's O(nlogn)?

Comment: Nitpick: It's called the `Master theorem`, not Master Method. I've never seen anyone ever call it the Master Method before and such a term appears to have effectively zero hits on Google for me. Regardless: Upvoting because this is the easiest way to prove complexities for recursive tasks like what the OP asked for.

Comment: There are [some places](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/lectures/lec20-master/lec20.html) where it is called Master Method, but you are right. It is known as Master's Theorem. I edited the answer.

Comment: The images in this post have since broken.

Comment: @kaya3 how do you write latex equations here?

Answer (score 0):

It is O(n).

Look at the recursion tree: (ignoring the constant factor that O(n) term should have)

[image]

The non-recursive version of the above is the sum of the right branches or

```
T(n) = n + (9/10) n + (9/10)^2 n + (9/10)^3 n + ...
```

which reduces to

```
T(n) = n * (1 + (9/10) + (9/10)^2 + (9/10)^3) + ... )
```

which means T(n) is some constant -- I think 10? -- times n, but in any case it is O(n) asymptotically.

Comment: This is not O(n). https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-solve-time-complexity-recurrence-relations-using-recursion-tree-method/